# Multiple pagination in single page - yii2 framewrok

Tags: php, yii2

Controller =>

```
public function getPagination($query, $pageSize) {

    $queryDataCount = new Pagination(['totalCount' => $query->count()]);

    $queryDataCount->setPageSize($pageSize);

    $paginatedData = $query->offset($queryDataCount->offset)
    ->limit($queryDataCount->limit)
    ->all();   

    return array($paginatedData, $queryDataCount);
}

$queryMonthly   = QuizLeaderboard::find()
->select(['SUM(score) as totalScore', 'SUM(time) as totalTime', 'userId'])
->where(['between', 'currentDate', $monthStart, $monthEnd])
->asArray();

$paginatedQueryMonthly = $this->getPagination($queryMonthly, 10);       
//$paginatedQueryMonthly[1]->pageParam = 'list1Page';

$queryWeekly   = QuizLeaderboard::find()
->select(['SUM(score) as totalScore', 'SUM(time) as totalTime', 'userId'])
->where(['between', 'currentDate', $monthStartSec, $monthEndSec])
->asArray();

 $paginatedQueryWeekly =$this->getPagination($queryWeekly, 10);
 $paginatedQueryWeekly[1]->pageParam = 'list2Page';



$queryTwoWeeks   = QuizLeaderboard::find()
 ->select(['SUM(score) as totalScore', 'SUM(time) as totalTime', 'userId'])
 ->where(['between', 'currentDate', $monthStartTh, $monthEndTh])
 ->asArray();

 $paginatedQueryTwoWeeks =$this->getPagination($queryTwoWeeks, 10);
 $paginatedQueryTwoWeeks[1]->pageParam = 'list3Page';
```

This is how i am sending data to view=>

```
 return $this->render('summarize-report', [

            'queryMonthly' => $paginatedQueryMonthly[0],
            'pagesQueryMonthly' => $paginatedQueryMonthly[1],

            'queryWeekly' => $paginatedQueryWeekly[0],
            'pagesQueryWeekly' => $paginatedQueryWeekly[1],

            'queryTwoWeeks' => $paginatedQueryTwoWeeks[0],
            'pagesQueryTwoWeeks' => $paginatedQueryTwoWeeks[1],
            'reports' => $query,
   ]);
```

View=>

```
echo LinkPager::widget([‘pagination’ => $pagesQueryWeekly,]);

echo LinkPager::widget([‘pagination’ => $pagesQueryTwoWeeks,]);

echo LinkPager::widget([ ‘pagination’ => $pagesQueryMonthly,]);
```

I have three paginator in one page. I have set different pageParam  for each pagination. But, Pagination is not changing pages. can anyone help me find out the problem?

Comment: Try `‘pagination’ => $pagesQueryWeekly[1]`

Comment: The `LinkPager::widget([‘pagination’ => PAGINATION_OBJECT_HERE])` so in your case pagination object is element with index [1]

Comment: @ustmaestro This won't work! Please check the question gain! i have added the part how i am passing data to view.

Comment: You're setting `pageParam` after pagination is used, so new value of `pageParam` is ignored.

Comment: @rob006 You are right! solved it already. Thanks!